# How I can move messages to another folder in Outlook in python

Tags: python, api, for-loop, microsoft-graph-api, move

I would like to move my mails into a subfolder with my python script.

Unfortunately, the `move`command does not work the way I want.

Any suggestions?

Here is the code I mentioned:

```
for message in testing.get_messages():
    print(message)
    if message.subject is not None and '<noticket>' in message.subject:
        message.mark_as_read()
        message.move('Inbox/Testing/NoTicket')
    else:
        print ("Checking...")
        message.move('Inbox/Testing/Processed')
```

I use [O365](https://pypi.org/project/O365/) as a Python package.

Error message from Microsoft Graph Explorer:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorInvalidUser",
        "message": "The requested user 'testmail@testmail.com' is invalid.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-06-23T16:59:42",
            "request-id": "...",
            "client-request-id": "..."
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "move command does not work the way I want" ? What is the problem with your code ?

Comment: It looks like I am requesting the wrong thing, see Client error.

Here the mails should be moved to a subfolder of `Testing` after they have been read.

The question is how can I do that?

Comment: There is something wrong in your url, "/messages/=/move" you should replace "=" with a valid ID.

Comment: I checked it and the problem looks like `"code": "ErrorInvalidUser",`. So the ID is there.

Comment: Well the error is now more explicit. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to solve my problem :)

```
processed = testing.get_folder(folder_name='Processed')
for message in testing.get_messages():
    print(message)
    if message.subject is not None and '<noticket>' in message.subject:
        message.mark_as_read()
    else:
        print ("Checking...")
        print(message.move)
        message.move(processed)
```